# Magento file upload with Varien_File_Uploader fails - $_FILES['tmp_name'] file doesn't exist

Tags: php, magento, file-upload

I've included observer code in my custom module for 'customer_save_before' event. It fires when customer submits his details in Magento front, account management area. It executes a script that should intercept $_FILES[...] array and use Varien_File_Uploader to save it in database.

I added a new field to .../template/customer/form/edit.phtml

```
<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" title="<?php echo $this->__('Logo') ?>" class="input-file" />
```

This is my Observer.php code that extcutes on 'customer_save_before':

```
class Walder_Logoupload_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

 public function customer_save_before($observer) {

    // Test code START

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);

        $tempexists = file_exists($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'])?'exists':'doesnt exist';
        echo "logo.tmp_name file: ".$tempexists;
        exit;

    // Test code END

        if(isset($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {
          try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('logo');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

            $path       = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'catalog'.DS.'customer'.DS.'logo';
            $newName    = time() . $_FILES['logo']['name'];
            $uploader->save($path, $newName);
            $customer->setLogo($newName);
          }catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "Exception: ".$e; exit;
          }
        }
 }
}
```

After file upload, with test code enabled I get an array that contains file info along with 'tmp_name' path and a message that temp file doesn't exist:

```
[logo] => Array
    (
        [name] => sample-logo.png
        [type] => image/png
        [tmp_name] => /home/www/mag59212/tmp/phpbCoax5
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 107564
    )

logo.tmp_name file: doesnt exist
```

With test code commented out I get this Exception error message:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'File was not uploaded.' 
in /home/www/mag59212/html/magento-de/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php:153
```

Which means the same, $_FILES['tmp_name'] file does not exist. In consequence the file is not saved on the server.

When I run this Observer code in back end I get same messages for my test code(file doesnt exist) but the file gets uploaded anyway.

How do I fix my front end code to upload this file?

Comment: Have you add the enctype declaration to the form? (enctype="multipart/form-data")

Comment: @sulman yes, I've added this already.

Comment: Alan how you have resolved this issue in observer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Did you checked the system log?

> MAGENTO FOLDER/var/log/system.log

For me it says:

> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/tmp/phpSJjFIv) is not within the allowed path(s): (...) /httpdocs/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php on line 150

Look up the php settings in php.ini, or phpinfo(). Search for "open_basedir" and "upload_tmp_dir". If the open_basedir restriction is set, and the upload_tmp_dir is not in the allowed directories, it could fire up such an error.

Answer (score 0):

At my end the issue was on file:
Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php at code :

```
 $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
```

in $customerData my file custom attribute is also receiving when compactData function called it removed the file.
and it included due to the following line in attribute creation in setup file:

```
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
```

when I removed the above line from the custom attribute setup line it resolve the issue.
hope will helpful to someone having similar issue,